# ReactJS displaying / hiding parallel components

Tags: reactjs

Preface: I'm very new to ReactJS, so my question will reflect my lack of understanding of how things work. Right now I'm using React + Alt.

I have a basic page with a parent component (I'll call it `MyContainer`) that has multiple parallel panel-esque components (`MyPanel`) displayed side by side. What I'm now trying to implement is each panel component has an Expand icon that when clicked, will make that panel take up the full width of its parent container (ie. `width:100%`) and hide all other panels (ie: `display:none` or `visibility:hidden`). When the button is clicked again, the initial state of all panels is again shown.

So my question is the proper way to implement this in ReactJS/Alt. So far I have the easy part done, which is listening for the Expand button click and updating the state of whether the panel should be displayed as normal or full-width.

```
export default class MyPanel extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      expanded: false
    };
    this.handleExpand = this.handleExpand.bind(this);
  }

  handleExpand() {
    this.setState({ expanded: !this.state.expanded });
  }

  render() {
    var expandStyle = {};
    if (this.state.expanded) {
        expandStyle.width = 'calc(100% - 40px)';
    }

    return(
      <div style={expandStyle}>
        <ExpandButton onExpandEvent={this.handleExpand} />
        {/* Rest of panel props data rendered here */} 
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The part I don't know how to do is have this component tell its sibling components whether they should hide or show itself. Trying to find similar questions here, I *think* there are two approaches: using props in the parent component to keep track of which panels are hidden or shown, or using Store/Actions to keep track of this, but I'm not sure on the implementation of either.

Again, I'm new to ReactJS, so go easy on me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your methodology for how to expand/hide slightly off: since your panels are all encompassed within a parent component, that component should decide if an individual panel is normal, expanded, or hidden. You should be using the state of the parent component to accomplish this, rather than the state of each panel component. For example:

```
var Container = React.createClass({
  getInitialState () {
    return {
      expandedPanel: null,
      panels: someArrayOfPanelData
    };
  },
  changeExpandedPanel (panelIndex) {
    return () => {
      this.setState({
        expandedPanel: panelIndex
      });
    };
  },
  render () {
    let panels = this.state.panels.map((panelData, i) => {
      return (
        <Panel 
          key={i} 
          data={panelData} 
          expanded={(i == this.state.panelExpanded)} 
          handleExpansion={this.changeExpandedPanel(i)}
        />
      );
    });

    return (
      <div>
        {panels}
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var Panel = React.createClass({
  propTypes: {
    ...,
    handleExpansion: React.PropTypes.function.isRequired
  },
  handleExpand () {
    this.props.handleExpansion();
  },
  render () {
    ...
  }
});
```

What you are doing here is passing the parent's event handler down to the children. Since the function is defined in the parent, it has access to the parent's state/props, etc.

Comment: Thanks. I had to make a couple of modifications. First, I removed the `(i)` from `handleExpansion={this.changeExpandedPanel(i)}` because that would execute `changeExpandedPanel` for each panel on initial render (and re-render). Next, I pulled the `setState` outside of the `return() =>` block, as I couldn't get my panels to rerender. I'm using React.Component instead of Class, so I'm not sure if that has something to do with it.

Comment: What I was trying to do was call `changeExpandedPanel` with the correct index and then return a function (with a reference to that index) for callback inside `Panel`. Sorry you had to change some things to get it to work.

Comment: Yah, I moved the index into the Panel class. I was able to figure out the intent of your code well enough. Thanks again!